# {"0":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name'

Tags: magento2, database, sql, magento2.2.8

Any Help Highly Admired, i'm using Magento 2.2.8

did all commands,upgrade, reindex, static file , etc still not worked

```
{"0":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`size`, `e`.`size_value`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`swatch_image`, `e`.`is_featured`, `e`.`sw_featured`, SUM(soi.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order`.`state`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `opp_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN `opp_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0\n INNER JOIN `opp_catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id='2'\n LEFT JOIN `opp_sales_order_item` AS `soi` ON soi.product_id = e.entity_id\n INNER JOIN `opp_sales_order` AS `order` ON order.entity_id = soi.order_id\n LEFT JOIN `opp_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (order.state <> 'canceled' and soi.parent_item_id IS NULL AND soi.product_id IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY `soi`.`product_id` ORDER BY `ordered_qty` DESC\n LIMIT 8","1":"#0 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Statement\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)\n#1 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Statement.php(303): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Statement\\Pdo\\Mysql->_execute(Array)\n#2 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)\n#3 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)\n#4 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(533): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)\n#5 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(605): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)\n#6 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php(737): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select), Array)\n#7 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection\/Db\/FetchStrategy\/Query.php(21): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select), Array)\n#8 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection\/AbstractDb.php(774): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection\\Db\\FetchStrategy\\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select), Array)\n#9 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(1115): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection\\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select))\n#10 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/Collection\/Interceptor.php(1129): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->_loadEntities(false, false)\n#11 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(913): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->_loadEntities(false, false)\n#12 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/Collection.php(777): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->load(false, false)\n#13 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection->load(false, false)\n#14 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->___callParent('load', Array)\n#15 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#16 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/Collection\/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)\n#17 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection.php(831): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->load()\n#18 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/Collection\/Interceptor.php(1766): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection->getIterator()\n#19 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php(348): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->getIterator()\n#20 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Smartwave\/Filterproducts\/Block\/Home\/BestsellersList\/Interceptor.php(180): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->getIdentities()\n#21 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php(71): Smartwave\\Filterproducts\\Block\\Home\\BestsellersList\\Interceptor->getIdentities()\n#22 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor), '\\n<script>\\n    t...')\n#23 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#24 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)\n#25 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput()\n#26 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php(170): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#27 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#28 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)\n#29 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#30 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)\n#31 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(139): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#32 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#33 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#34 \/home\/cellbezc\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#35 {main}","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"
```

Comment: When you get this?

Comment: i have disabled one module after it

Answer (score 2):

It's problem with this module:

```
Smartwave_Filterproducts
```

disable it and check is it better.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Smartwave_Filterproducts
```

It looks like it's missing something in database.

Try later enable it again  and run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Delete also generated -  rm -rf generated/*

Comment: thanks let me check now

Comment: very good debug @BartZalas

Comment: not worked BarZalas

Comment: any new errors when is disabled? Try disable and run this command rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/* pub/static/frontend/* generated/code/*

Answer (score 1):

```
          **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name'**
```

> No need to  disable "Smartwave_Filterproducts".

This error occurs bocz your db table consider as table table catalog_product_flat_1  and inside product **name** field exist ...check your admin
i am sure you selected below two option "yes"

> stores >> configuration >> catalog >> storefront

```
 -Use Flat Catalog Product - yes

 -Use Flat Category Product - yes
```

means Using **Flat Catalog** will help you speed up your product collection instead of managing the catalog data in many tables by the Entity Attribute Value (EAV). When your store applies the Flat Catalog, the new tables on the fly are generated and they will store all necessary data related to your products or categories.

The flat catalog is **updated automatically and quickly in every minute or according to your cron job regradless** that your catalog contains more than 500,000 SKUs. Apparently, the flat catalog can also **speed up the processing of catalog** and cart price rules without any difficulties.

**I recommend to you** **please set to No** below two option  from admin:

> stores >> configuration >> catalog >> storefront

```
    - Use Flat Catalog Product - no

    - Use Flat Category Product - no
```

and run the below commands

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Now, check your frontend error solve...blahhh...blahhhh

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the filter module should be disabled or fixed.
A theme/ plugin that cannot handle magento flat catalog should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As has been already mentioned is the Smartwave_Filterproducts. This is happening if anyone is using the block Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\BestsellersList that is actually causing the issue.

This block is directly querying the table catalog_product_entity but Magento, with flat table enabled, supposed to have more fields ( name in this case ).

The solution that I adopted was to change the block and double check if the flat is enabled. This is the piece of code if anyone is interested in :

Line 42:

```
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    if ($collection->isEnabledFlat()) {
        $mainTable = 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId;
    } else {
        $mainTable = 'catalog_product_entity';
    }
    $collection->getSelect()->join(['e' => $connection->getTableName($mainTable)],'');
```